# Sql Query to select a column value with an aggregate funtion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table: (tblUser)

```
 ______________________________
|Column Name  |  Data Type     |
|------------------------------|
|     ID      |     bigint     |
|  UserName   | nvarchar(100)  |
|  Password   | nvarchar(100)  |
|   Email     | nvarchar(200)  |
|  UserType   |      bit       |
|_____________|________________|
```

This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE Procedure spAutheticateUser
@UserName nvarchar(100),
@Password nvarchar(200)
as
Begin
  Declare @Count int
  Declare @Type bit

  Select @Count = COUNT(UserName), @Type = UserType from tblUsers
  where [UserName] = @UserName and [Password] = @Password

  If (@Count = 1 and @Type = 'True')
  Begin
      Select 1 as ReturnCode
  End
  Else If (@Count = 1 and @Type = 'False')
  Begin
      Select 2 as ReturnCode
  End
  Else
  Begin
      Select -1 as ReturnCode
  End
End
```

This is the error I get on SQLServer:

> Column 'tblUsers.UserType' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Actually I want to call this stored procedure behind loginButton_click function. I want to validate User information and I also want to check which type the user belongs to. Depending on the UserType I will redirect to a specific page.

Kindly guide me on how to achieve the functionality. Thanks.

Comment: add `group by UserType` to the query.

Comment: Where's UserName field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your select statement as below:

```
Select @Count = COUNT(UserName), @Type = UserType from tblUsers
where [UserName] = @UserName and [Password] = @Password
GROUP By UserType
```

You are going to use aggregate function, so you have to group by remain column , which you have select

Comment: Thanks. There is no error now but ELSE IF is not executing.

Comment: You have declare @type as int and comparing with string value

Comment: Its a typo. Actually @type is bit. Edited the question.

Comment: then compare @type=1 OR @type=0

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were a great help.

Comment: Well that *technically* solves it, but now `COUNT` doesn't find duplicate user names anymore, so why aggregate at all? This answer makes no sense in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding group by UserType to the main query. is there any particular reason you are getting a count(@UserName)? If you remove the count function then you dont need a Group By clause.

Comment: Thanks, But ELSE IF is still not executing

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether there is more than one record for the user name in the table. In case there are more records, there can be different UserTypes. As you are not interested in the UserType once there is more than one record, simply pick the minimum or maximum UserType.

```
select @Count = COUNT(UserName), @Type = MIN(UserType) 
from tblUsers
where [UserName] = @UserName and [Password] = @Password
```

The whole thing:

```
select 
  case
    when count(*) = 1 and min(usertype) = 'True' then 1
    when count(*) = 1 and min(usertype) = 'False' then 2
    else -1
  end as returncode
from tblusers
where username = @UserName and password = @Password
```

Comment: UserType has a bit datatype so its not valid for min operator

Comment: Then convert it. Using `case` to convert to string: `min(case when usertype = 1 then 'True' else 'False' end)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a strict answer to your question, but some tips strongly related to your functionality:

```
DECLARE
    @pwd_1 NVARCHAR(100),
    @pwd_2 NVARCHAR(100)

SET @pwd_1 = 'asdf'
SET @pwd_2 = 'asdf   '

SELECT 'access granted'
WHERE @pwd_1 = @pwd_2


SET @pwd_1 = 'ASDF'
SET @pwd_2 = 'asdf'

SELECT 'access granted'
WHERE @pwd_1 = @pwd_2
```

[image]